# Which Boost version should I use with a C++03-capable compiler?

Tags: c++, boost, version, compatibility, c++03

My compiler supports C++03. Which version of boost should I therefore use? If I was using an earlier version of C++, how would I establish the boost version?

Comment: A golden rule for open-source software: Always use the latest (stable) version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whichever. Boost libraries are smart enough to detect your C++ version and compiler and with some preprocessor magic provide implementations that will work with it. So you could as well use the latest version which has more bugs fixed and broader functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Every boost version has its ["tested compilers" list](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_51_0.html) (scroll this page to the end). This is the place where you should check whether your compiler version is supported or not.